# python function to return items in list of dictionaries in json format as strings on new line

Tags: python, json, list

lets say i have

```
POSTS = [{"author":"david icke", "username":"davidicke", "date-published":"January 01 2020"}, {"author":"jordan maxwell", "username":"jordanmaxwell", "date-published":"January 02 2020"}]
```

how do i write a function that will iterate over the authors and return the values of authors
like below

```
author: david icke
username: davidicke

author: jordan maxwell
username: jordanmaxwell
```

i have tried many things and am only able to figure out how to return just first values as below

```
david ickeauthor: jordan maxwell
```

here is what i have currently

```
POSTS = [
    {
    "fullname":"david icke",
    "username":"davidicke",
    "date-published":"August 1st, 2020"
    },
    {
    "fullname":"jordan maxwell",
    "username":"jordanmaxwell",
    "date-published":"August 2nd, 2020"
    }
]

def home():
    newlist = []
    for post in POSTS:
        newlist.append(post["fullname"])
        responce = "author: \n".join(map(str, newlist))
    return responce
```

> **How do i achieve to return this?**

```
author: david icke
username: davidicke

author: jordan maxwell
username: jordanmaxwell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should not be part of the for loop. You also shouldn't need the map function since the elements are already strings.

```
responce = "author: \n".join(map(str, newlist))
```

To get the formatting you can replace your `home` function with something like this:

```
def home():
    data = ["Author {} \n User {}".format(post["fullname"], post["username"]) for post in POST]
    return "\n".join(data)
```

Alternative with loop instead:

```
def home():
  result = []
  for post in POST:
    result.append("Author {} \n User {}".format(post["fullname"], post["username"]))
  return "\n".join(result)
```

Comment: Added another example using a loop instead of comprehension

Comment: it doesn't print to new line..it keeps printing to one line..but i guess it is flask not rendering it well..this is function in flask app

Comment: If it's being displayed in a browser replace \n with <br>. That will break the line but depending on the surrounding content might not be what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.items()` to iterate through list of tuples like `[(key, value), ...]`:

```
def prettify_data(data):
    response = ""
    for e in data:
            for key, value in e.items():
                    if key == "date-published": continue
                    response += key+': '+value+'\n'
            response += '\n'
    return response
```

Here is the result:

```
>>> print(prettify_data(POSTS))
author: david icke
username: davidicke

author: jordan maxwell
username: jordanmaxwell
```

Comment: getting errors with the function on this line `response += key+': '+value`